# Нужно в третьем блоке case изменить поля объектов динамического массива arraylist

Tags: java, классы, arraylist

Думал, через индексы get`рами и set'терами всё поизменять, но не смог обратиться к объекту по индексу.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

   static Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<record> records = new ArrayList<record>();

   for (int i=0;i!=1;){
   System.out.println("Что ты хочешь?\n1)Добавить запись\n2)Удалить запись\n3)Редактировать запись\n4)Показать запись\n5)Закончить программу");
   int op = input.nextInt();
   switch (op){
   case 1:

       records.add(new record());

       break;
       case 2:
           System.out.println("Введите индек записи, которую хотите удалить:");
           int b = input.nextInt();
           records.remove(b);
           break;
           //---------------------------------------
           //c этим блоком case 3 нужна помощь 
       case 3:
           System.out.println("Введите индекс записи:");
           int d = input.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Что добрый молодец хочет отредачить?\n1)Имя записи\n2)дату\n3)автора\n4)саму запись\n5)задачу");
           int c=input.nextInt();
           switch (c){
               case 1:
                   System.out.println("Введите новое имя записи:");
                   //тут нужно изменить поле name объекта типа record 
                   break;
               case 2:
                   System.out.println("Введите новую дату:");
                  // тут новую дату поставить
                   break;
               case 3:
                   System.out.println("Введите новое имя автора:");
                   //тут нужно изменить поле author объекта типа record 
                   break;
               case 4:
                   System.out.println("Введите запись:");
                   //тут нужно изменить поле record объекта типа record 
                   break;
               case 5:
                   System.out.println("Введите новую задачу:");
//тут нужно изменить поле tasks объекта типа record 
                   break;
           }
           break;
           //=-----------------------------------------------------------------
       case 4:
           System.out.println("Введите индекс записи:");
           int a = input.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Название записи:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).name);
           System.out.println("Дата записи:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).date);
           System.out.println("Автор записи:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).author);
           System.out.println("Сама Запись:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).record);
           System.out.println("Задачи:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).tasks);
break;
       case 5: i=1;
   }}
   //

   }
}



public  class record {

   Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);

   // name
   String name;
   // date
   Date date = new Date();
   //author
   String author;
   //record
   String record;
   //tasks
   String tasks;
   record (){
       System.out.println("Input name:");
       name = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println(date);
       System.out.println("Input author:");
       author = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Input record:");
       record = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Input tasks:");
       tasks = input.nextLine();

   };



   public Date getDate() {
       return date;
   }

   public Scanner getInput() {
       return input;
   }

   public String getAuthor() {
       return author;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public String getRecord() {
       return record;
   }

   public String getTasks() {
       return tasks;
   }

   public void setAuthor(String author) {
       this.author = author;
   }

   public void setDate(Date date) {
       this.date = date;
   }

   public void setInput(Scanner input) {
       this.input = input;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public void setRecord(String record) {
       this.record = record;
   }

   public void setTasks(String tasks) {
       this.tasks = tasks;
   }
}

   package com.company;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

   static Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<record> records = new ArrayList<record>();

   for (int i=0;i!=1;){
   System.out.println("Что ты хочешь?\n1)Добавить запись\n2)Удалить запись\n3)Редактировать запись\n4)Показать запись\n5)Закончить программу");
   int op = input.nextInt();
   switch (op){
   case 1:

       records.add(new record());

       break;
       case 2:
           System.out.println("Введите индек записи, которую хотите удалить:");
           int b = input.nextInt();
           records.remove(b);
           break;
           //---------------------------------------
           //c этим блоком case 3 нужна помощь 
       case 3:
           System.out.println("Введите индекс записи:");
           int d = input.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Что добрый молодец хочет отредачить?\n1)Имя записи\n2)дату\n3)автора\n4)саму запись\n5)задачу");
           int c=input.nextInt();
           switch (c){
               case 1:
                   System.out.println("Введите новое имя записи:");
                   //тут нужно изменить поле name объекта типа record 
                   break;
               case 2:
                   System.out.println("Введите новую дату:");
                  // тут новую дату поставить
                   break;
               case 3:
                   System.out.println("Введите новое имя автора:");
                   //тут нужно изменить поле author объекта типа record 
                   break;
               case 4:
                   System.out.println("Введите запись:");
                   //тут нужно изменить поле record объекта типа record 
                   break;
               case 5:
                   System.out.println("Введите новую задачу:");
//тут нужно изменить поле tasks объекта типа record 
                   break;
           }
           break;
           //=-----------------------------------------------------------------
       case 4:
           System.out.println("Введите индекс записи:");
           int a = input.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Название записи:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).name);
           System.out.println("Дата записи:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).date);
           System.out.println("Автор записи:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).author);
           System.out.println("Сама Запись:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).record);
           System.out.println("Задачи:");
           System.out.println(records.get(a).tasks);
break;
       case 5: i=1;
   }}
   //

   }
}



public  class record {

   Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);

   // name
   String name;
   // date
   Date date = new Date();
   //author
   String author;
   //record
   String record;
   //tasks
   String tasks;
   record (){
       System.out.println("Input name:");
       name = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println(date);
       System.out.println("Input author:");
       author = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Input record:");
       record = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Input tasks:");
       tasks = input.nextLine();

   };



   public Date getDate() {
       return date;
   }

   public Scanner getInput() {
       return input;
   }

   public String getAuthor() {
       return author;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public String getRecord() {
       return record;
   }

   public String getTasks() {
       return tasks;
   }

   public void setAuthor(String author) {
       this.author = author;
   }

   public void setDate(Date date) {
       this.date = date;
   }

   public void setInput(Scanner input) {
       this.input = input;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public void setRecord(String record) {
       this.record = record;
   }

   public void setTasks(String tasks) {
       this.tasks = tasks;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           case 1:
               System.out.println("Введите новое имя записи:");
               //тут нужно изменить поле name объекта типа record 
               input.nextLine();
               records.get(d).setName(input.nextLine());
               break;
```

Comment: я затестил, твоя строчка не сработала(

Comment: @MaksBerd Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: аккуратно, попробуйте у себя запустить, если не верите

Comment: Благодарю, заработало, не знал, что можно без записи в переменную так делать)

Comment: @MaksBerd На здоровье. Успехов.